# Ubuntu installation on Acer Aspire Cloudbook 11

Tags: boot, uefi, acer

Ubuntu installation on Acer Aspire Cloudbook 11

Installation required these steps:

Download Ubuntu 14.04 ISO file from Ubuntu website.

Create a “start-up disk” on a USB stick or SD card, 2GB+ (this small laptop has no CD-ROM drive) using Start-up Disk Creator

Turn on the Acer and call up the BIOS when the “Acer – Explore beyond limits” screen appears. Navigate using keys listed at the bottom.

Use the right arrow to highlight the “Boot” menu, then the down arrow to highlight “USB HDD”. Then press <kbd>F6</kbd> to make this the first item on the list, then press <kbd>F10</kbd>.

The computer restarts. Pressing <kbd>F2</kbd> again to return to the BIOS screen.
Highlight the “Main” menu, press enter, then change the touch-pad type from “Advanced” to “Basic” and exit the BIOS.

Insert the Start-up USB disk (memory stick) and install Ubuntu.
After installing, shut down the system.

Having completely removed Windows, to boot after installation I returned to the BIOS screen, navigated to “Security”, went to “Select an UEFI file as trusted for executing”, and selected a file from the list that appeared. However there are also several files listed under Ubuntu:

- `shimx64.efi`
- `grubx64.efi`
- `MokManager.efi`

The system works but has generated a system fault warning on starting up again. I clicked on the send a report to Ubuntu button.

My question is: Which is the most appropriated UEFI file?

Comment: It would help to answer your question, if you also post which file you actually selected, and what exactly was the error text that is giving you a problem. Also, if the list of files you provided is not complete, it would be helpful to provide the full list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you installed Ubuntu in EFI mode with **Secure Boot enabled** :

The appropriate boot file you have to select is **shimx64.efi**.

When you installed Ubuntu in EFI mode with **Secure Boot disabled** :

The appropriate boot file you have to select  is **grubx64.efi**.

Comment: Thanks cl-netbox - happily using Ubuntu on my new netbook now.