# Installing Ubuntu on Acer Cloudbook 11

Tags: system-installation, kubuntu, usb-drive, acer

First question, all:

Based on this thread, I tried installing Kubuntu on an Acer Cloudbook 11: [Ubuntu installation on Acer Aspire Cloudbook 11](https://askubuntu.com/questions/715407/ubuntu-installation-on-acer-aspire-cloudbook-11)

However, the granularity of the instructions is quite variable and is making the process difficult to follow. At this point, I've created Kubuntu USB install drives with both Kubuntu 14 and 16, and they both do the same thing. The machine boots from either (BIOS adjustments for boot order and touchpad alrady successfully done), but I try the option to boot or to install (for OEM's), and they both just lock up on a black screen, either version. Backlight still on, machine still on, but nothing on screen. Any ideas? HOw long should this bootup take, approximately? I waited about an hour on one occasion, and still nothin'.

Thanks for any help. Please do not respond that machine may be turned off or out of power (it's not), or that I need to rebuild the USB startup drive (already done multiple times, no error from Start-Up Disk Creator), or that Linux may not run on this machine (original post referenced indicates that it can). I don't mean to sound snippy, especially when I'm asking for help, but I've consistently gotten responses in online forums that either ignore important parts of the problem description or say things that are not true, and that can be very frustrating (I was once told that a 128 MB machine could not run a Linux GUI for SUSE 9, and that is patently not true).

Thanks for any and all help, I'd really like to get this going.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, I solved this problem using

```
noapic 

nolapic 

acpi=off
```

boot parameters and using the BIOS legacy.